# Rails best way to write to a file with specific spacing?

Tags: ruby, file

I have to write a text file in Ruby from a rake task, however I have to output the data in a very specific format.

field length: 20, last name
field length: 15, first name
field length: 10, middle name

All the names can be of varying length and there may be more fields to add to this.

Is there any best practice or a templating system I could put to use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) type formatting usually does the job. For example:

```
'%20s %15s %10s' % [ last_name, first_name, middle_name ]
```

You can adjust that as required.

Comment: Yes awesome! Im kind of a noob to ruby and wasn't sure if ruby had something C-ish like this.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're committed to learning Ruby, take some time to read through the documentation bit by bit. [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html) is full of handy methods like this, and other classes are similarly full-featured.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's possible it's without spaces at all, wasn't sure exactly how to interpret it.